# Avoiding from browser security warning about untrusted certificates in on-premise app

Tags: security, browser, ssl, certificate

My company has an on-premise web application. Each customer has it own environment installation.

Each time a user connects to the webapp (https://10.0.1.2 or https://10.0.2.2) the browser identify the certificate as untrusted.

There is a way to avoid this problem, to the browser identify the certificate as trusted? 
There are certificates that we can buy to be used in on-premises environments?

Comment: you need to install the cert as a trusted root in each user's web browser. you should probably use a hostname instead of an IP address though

Comment: Or use a legit hostname (e.g. internalwebapp.customersdomain.com) that's only served by the internal DNS, and then you can get a cert from a real (trusted) CA.